# Javascript Text effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a JS plugin, which will take in a string as input, and the string will slowly lose characters, one from each end at a time, and eventually vanish (string length = 0).

This is the code I have written so far :

```
var start=0;
var finish=0;

$.fn.scramble = function(){
     $(this).each(function(){
       $element = $(this);
       $inputString = $element.text().trim();
       finish = $inputString.length;
       vanish($inputString.substring(start++, finish--));
     })
  }

vanish = function($inputString){
  console.log($inputString);
  $stringLength = $inputString.length;
  console.log($stringLength);
  if($stringLength <= 0)
     return 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    vanish($inputString.substring(start++, finish--));
   }, 1000);
 }
```

I am giving it a sample input, "Samples". The expected output is "ample", "mpl", "p". But instead it returns "ample", "ple".

Surely, I am doing something wrong here, but I am unable to figure it out. Kindly help :)

Here's a fiddle set up : http://jsfiddle.net/v6KKM/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v6KKM/3/ ;-)

Comment: Oh!My bad. That was way too silly. Thank you very much :) @MartyIX

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing `finish = $inputString.length;` to `finish = $inputString.length - 1;`

Comment: But the substring function will return from start index to finish index-1. If i do `finish = $inputString.length - 1;`, it will automatically omit the last letter, which I don't want to happen

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.scramble = function(){
     $(this).each(function(){
       $element = $(this);
       $inputString = $element.text().trim();
       finish = $inputString.length;
       vanish($inputString.slice(1, -1));
     })
  }

vanish = function($inputString){
  console.log($inputString);
  $stringLength = $inputString.length;
  // console.log($stringLength);
  if($stringLength <= 0)
     return 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    vanish($inputString.slice(1, -1));
   }, 1000);
 }
```

Maybe this what you want. 
You can compare '[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)' and '[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)'. I hope this does help.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the same result in easier way using arrays and recursive function
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/xkCT8/2/)
all code you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.scramble = function(){
        var str=$(this).text()
        function recursor(str){
            newS=''
            if(str.length>=3){
                var arr=str.split('')
                arr.pop()
                arr.shift()
                for(a=0;a<arr.length;a++){newS+=arr[a]}
                $('#text').append(' '+newS)
                setTimeout(function() { recursor(newS) },1000)
             }
        }
        recursor(str)
    }
    $('#sc').click(function(){
        $('#text').scramble()
    })  
})
</script>
```

or (brobably better) you ca use substring [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/39bHB/) and you'll obtain a more compact code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.scramble = function(){
        var str=$(this).text()
        function recursor(str){
            if(str.length>=3){
                var result = str.substring(1, str.length-1);
                $('#text').append(' '+result)
                setTimeout(function() { recursor(result) },1000)
             }
        }
        recursor(str)
    }
    $('#sc').click(function(){
        $('#text').scramble()
    })  
})
</script>
```

this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.